# Trying to synchronize a file writing system in java

Tags: java, concurrency

I am trying to synchronize a file cashing on the hard disk from the database.

What i am doing in checking if the file exists and if not i fetch the file from the database and deploy it. I would not like to write the file multiple times due to a Race condition.

Here is the code i made:

**IMPORTENT**: This code is inside a Bean with all its meanings

> ```
> @Override
> public String getThumbnailPictureUrl(Design design) {
>     String relativePath = String.format(THUMBNAIL_URL, design.getId(), design.getThumbnailPicture().getFileName());
>     String realPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/"+relativePath); 
>     logger.info("Request Thumbnail picture for design: " + design.getId());
>     logger.info("Thumbnail picture relative path: " + relativePath);
>     logger.info("Thumbnail picture real path: " + realPath);        
>     File file = new File(realPath);
>     if(!file.exists()) 
>     {
>         synchronized (thumbnailLock) 
>         {
>             if(!file.exists()) 
>             {
>             logger.warn("Could not fild file in path: " + realPath);
>             FileAttachment pictureAttachment = design.getThumbnailPicture();
>             Hibernate.initialize(pictureAttachment.getAttachment());
>             Data data = (Data) pictureAttachment.getAttachment();
>             file = toolBox.convertBlobToFile(data.getBlob(), file);
>             logger.warn("file created in path: " + realPath);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return relativePath;
> }
> ```

With this solution in case i don't find the file i really wont write the file 2 times as well as any other file as i am synchronizing the entire block for all threads trying to reach it even if is to write a different file.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about creating a `HashMap` of locks? The key will be the file path and the value will be just an object used as lock. Let's say this map is defined like this:

```
Map<String, Object> locks = new Map<String, Object>();
```

And this is the use:

```
if(!file.exists()) 
{
    Object lock = null;
    synchronized (locks) {
       lock = locks.get(file.getName());
       if(lock == null) {
            lock = new Object();
            locks.put(file.getName(), lock);

       }
    }
    synchronized (lock) 
    {
        if(!file.exists()) 
        {
        logger.warn("Could not fild file in path: " + realPath);
        FileAttachment pictureAttachment = design.getThumbnailPicture();
        Hibernate.initialize(pictureAttachment.getAttachment());
        Data data = (Data) pictureAttachment.getAttachment();
        file = toolBox.convertBlobToFile(data.getBlob(), file);
        logger.warn("file created in path: " + realPath);
        }
    }
    synchronized(locks) { 
         map.remove(lock)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: File paths are dynamic. i cannot create a key/object on the fly and lock it... it has the same race condition potential. by the time i lock the object, the following thread will already replace it with a new one

Comment: Have a look at my code, I think it solves all of the race conditions. At least the ones I could think of.

Comment: There's still some waiting for all of the files. But the original critical section is locked per file. The `locks` table operations are not very costly (in time-processing)

Comment: I see what you did there...,
Interesting if others approve of this i will too

Comment: `map.remove(lock);` isn't do what you think, in this case, nothing. I think you mean `map.remove(file.getName());`

Comment: Why are you not using `ConcurrentHashMap`, at least?

Answer (score 5):

Similar to  @Avi's solution but using a ConcurrentHashMap.

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

String name = file.getName();
Object lock = map.get(name);
if (lock == null) {
    map.putIfAbsent(name, new Object());
    lock = map.get(name);
}

synchronized (lock) {
    // do something
}

map.remove(name);
```

Comment: your solution creates new Object each time file existence is queried, so it is not always better than @Avi's solution.